# Twitter bot script

Tags: function, bots

So I am trying to write a twitter bot script just for practice. When I run the script it throws an error.
this is what I have

```
import tweepy
import time


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler ('g8tFLVnImSSbV8bretFmmpG6D','A040svsUjF3sovM7kKZdPE2Z8W1GKMPIQos7oHAM290NWMF7j8')

auth.set_access_token('1443589399866855426-ZTsv2XybAPgtGslBElCujAfjRumtmp','Sb5AWSJnZuvwLkxLDPLsO9jizKK1reM4NJ8h2fG293P3G')

api = tweepy.API(auth), wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True

user = api.me()

print(user)
```

this is the error Im getting cannot assign function to call. but I have written this script on another computer this morning and the code is fine so I cannot seem to fin the error in my code

Comment: Are these real tokens in your code? If so, I would suggest regenerating any keys at this point.

Comment: I will regenerate once I get the code working thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
api = tweepy.API(auth), wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True
```

you should have

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

Comment: I corrected this stupid mistake but not I get unexpected key word argument ??